# $lookup with case sensitive fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I know how to do the case insensitive search.

example :

- members.email: `aaa@aaa.com` BUT :
- users.email: `AAA@aaa.com`

  ```
  db.getCollection('members').aggregate([
  {$lookup: {'from': 'users', 'localField': 'members.email', 'foreignField': 'email', 'as': 'users'}},
  {$unwind: {path: '$users', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
  {$match : { users: { $exists: false } }},
  ]);
  ```

collection member looks like:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b439c02a5439e00568291fe"),
"members" : [ 
    {
        "email" : "aaa@gmail.com"
    }, 
    {
        "email" : "bbb@gmail.com"
    }, 
    {
        "email" : "ccc@gmail.com"
    }
],
"groupname" : "abuse",
"active" : true,
"createdAt" : ISODate("2018-07-09T17:31:46.098Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-07-09T17:31:46.098Z"),
"__v" : 0
}
```

collection member_user looks like:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a7dfce545e13f0233b2e451"),
"email" : "AAA@gmail.com",
"__v" : 0
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b43ac89bfd90aa9cc4a68c2"),
"email" : "bbb@gmail.com",
"__v" : 0
}
```

This is code I use:

```
    db.getCollection('member').aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$members"},
    {$lookup: {'from': 'member_user', 'localField': 'members.email', 'foreignField': 'email', 'as': 'users'}},
    {$unwind: {path: '$users', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$match : { users: { $exists: false } }},
], 
{
    collation: {
        locale: 'en_US',
        strength: 1
    }
}
    );
```

when the dataset is small, the speed always very fast.  BUT I have 24K members and 7K users.  As I said, when {$match : { users: { $exists: true } }}, speed is OK, but when {$match : { users: { $exists: false } }}, speed almost 60 times.  (1 sec vs 1 min)

Without collation, the speed is always fast

Comment: what is your question here?

Comment: In  $lookup, aaa@aaa.com is NOT same as AAA@aaa.com.  So "users" will NOT exist after $unwind.  The result will have "aaa@aaa.com".  BUT I want to get "empty" result

Comment: so your `localField` and `foreignField` have case sensitive match?

Comment: I want my localField and foreignField have case insensitive match.  BUT looks now, they are case sensitive match.  How to make them case insensitive match?

Comment: 3.6.  I have tried: {
    collation: {
        locale: 'en_US',
        strength: 1
    }
}when I use aggregate.  Get a very weird result:  If I set {$match : { users: { $exists: true } }},  the result return very fast.  BUT if I set {$match : { users: { $exists: false } }}, the result returns extremely slow. (0.05 sec VS 3.43 sec)

Comment: Please check the answer

Comment: thanks for the answer, finally, I decided to change the schema to make sure all emails are saved in lower case to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the `localField` and `foreignField` into lower case using [`$toLower`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/) aggregation then you can easily match your fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$members" },
  { "$addFields": { "members.email": { "$toLower": "$members.email" }}},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "let": { "membersEmail": "$members.email" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$addFields": { "email": { "$toLower": "$email" }}},
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$email", "$$membersEmail" ] } } }
    ],
    "as": "members.email"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$members.email" },
  {  "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "groupname": { "$first": "$groupname" },
    "active": { "$first": "$active" },
    "members": { "$push": "$members.email" }
  }}
])
```